Android Compose LazyColumn change some values
How do I reflect changes in some values ​​in the List to LazyColumn in real time?
val postDataList = postViewModel.postDataList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(CustomColor.BackGround)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        state = postScrollState
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(postDataList.itemSnapshotList.items) { _, post ->
            Post(viewModel, userData, post)
        }
    }


kindly provide more details on what problem you are facing . Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You should also read How to Ask and edit your question to improve it.

usually devs put model object  's list , and uses the size of the list for items() , later you can use the {it -> }  it to modify the data inside list.

Can you please provide some code related to the lazy column?

I uploaded an example code
